How can I attach a resolver to a field in Appsync with SAM?
I have a GraphQL schema with a query. The query uses a lambda resolver that connects to a REST API and fetches the data. I want to have the field TimeSchedules on the type AccessGroup to use a different resolver and I've managed to get this to work in the console but it doesn't seem to be possible with SAM.
Parts of schema:
type Query {
  getAccessGroup(site: ID!, id: ID!): AccessGroup
}

type AccessGroup {
  id: ID!
  customerReference: String!
  lockCount: Int!
  userCount: Int!
  TimeSchedules: TimeSchedulesResults
}

On the REST Api access groups have time schedules but they're two different calls, and as I don't always need the latter, I think it's better to have it like this.
In SAM, I've tried this:
  GraphQLVBVAAPI:
      Type: AWS::Serverless::GraphQLApi
      Properties:
        SchemaUri: ./graphql/schema.graphql
        Resolvers:                                                 
          Query:
            getAccessGroup:
              Runtime:
                Name: APPSYNC_JS
                Version: "1.0.0"
              Pipeline:
                - lambdaResolver  
            AccessGroup:
              Runtime:
                Name: APPSYNC_JS
                Version: "1.0.0"
              Pipeline:
                - lambdaResolver

But then I get an error saying

No field named AccessGroup found on type Query

It might be possible to use a Cloud Formation <AWS::AppSync::Resolver here, but it looks like i have to write the whole resolver logic inline in the yaml schema..
  Resolver:
    Type: AWS::AppSync::Resolver
    Properties:
      ApiId: !GetAtt GraphQLVBVAAPI.ApiId 
      TypeName: AccessGroup
      FieldName: TimeSchedules
      DataSourceName: LambdaFunc     
      Runtime:
        Name: APPSYNC_JS
        RuntimeVersion: "1.0.0"
      Code: ./graphql/lambdaSubResolver.js 

Here I get error

The code contains one or more errors

Any suggestions?

The error No field named AccessGroup found on type Query says, there is no query field with AccessGroup this name. Please check your schema.graphql file.
